# Getting a heap error when trying to free

Tags: c, strcat

This smells like a heap corruption of some kind but I can not seem to find it.
the problem occurs on `string_utils_replace()` when trying to run `free(tmp_for_free)`. the function is supposed to replace every occurrence of `"search"` with `"replace"` in `"string"`.

```
char* string_utils_part_of_string(char *string, int from, int to)
{
    int size_to_allocate = to - from + 1;
    char *result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size_to_allocate);

    strncpy(result, string + from, to - from);
    result[size_to_allocate - 1] = '\0';

    return result;
}

char* string_utils_replace(char *search, char *replace, char *string)
{
    char *end, *result = string, *tmp_for_free = NULL;
    int before_replace, after_replace;
    int size_search = strlen(search);
    int size_replace = strlen(replace);
    int size_string, size_find;
    int first_time = 1;

    char *find = strstr(string, search);

    if (find == NULL)
        return string_utils_copy_string(string);

    while (find != NULL)
    {
        tmp_for_free = result;

        size_string = strlen(result);
        size_find = strlen(find);

        before_replace = size_string - size_find;
        after_replace = before_replace + size_replace;

        end = string_utils_part_of_string(result, after_replace, size_string);
        result = string_utils_part_of_string(result, 0, before_replace);
        strcat(result, replace);
        strcat(result, end);

        // no memory leaks, hooray!
        free(end);
        if (first_time == 0)
            free(tmp_for_free);

        size_string = strlen(result);
        find = strstr(result, search);
        first_time = 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: verify `end` isn't null before freeing it

Comment: first time loop runs `tmp_for_free = result;` assigns undefined result storage to tmp_for_free..

Comment: @Morb no, you don't need that, `free(NULL)` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @amdixon - no, result is equal to string in the first run. check the first line in the function

Comment: I'm too lazy to check the code, but can you double check that you've allocated enough memory to support those `strcat()`s?

Comment: well, this is probably it @SouravGhosh, I thought strcat() reallocs for you.

Comment: @GeorgeRubin well, you see, it does not. :-)

Comment: Do not use `strncpy()`.  It is never the right tool for anything.  Use `memcpy()` with the same arguments here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) of `strcat()`,

> `char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);`
>
> *[..]* and the dest string must have enough space for the result. If dest is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable;

In your `string_utils_part_of_string()` function, you did not allocate enough memory to the `result` to be able to hold the *entire* input, and later, you're trying to use the same pointer to store the *whole* input, through `strcat()`. This is creating the memory overrun which in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Note: Please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Answer (score 1):

You are causing a buffer overflow here:

```
    result = string_utils_part_of_string(result, 0, before_replace);
    strcat(result, replace);
    strcat(result, end);
```

`result` is allocated exactly `before_replace+1` bytes and initialized with `before_replace` bytes from the beginning of `string` and a final `'\0'`.  You cannot concatenate `replace` and `end` to this array, it is full already.

The logic in your function is convoluted. You should simplify it.  For instance, you should first run a loop counting the number of occurrences of `find` in `string`, then allocate a buffer for the result, then run a second loop copying fragments of `string` and copies of `replace`.

You should also test if `find` is an empty string.  `strstr()` will always find the empty string, causing your algorithm to loop endlessly.